# Using javaFX passwordfield

Tags: java, javafx, bcrypt

I am trying to implement bCrypt with a JavaFX passwordfield and i cant get it to work.  Can anyone give me a pointer? i have tried using passwordfield.equals .getpassword etc and it still doesnt work. it works if i test on the userId field.

```
 private void loginpressed(ActionEvent event) 

 {

    if (BCrypt.checkpw(passwordfield.getText(), passwordhash))
        System.out.println("It matches");
    else

                System.out.print("false");      
 }
@FXML
 TextField userId;
 TextField passwordfield;
 Button loginpressed;
```

Comment: It seems suspicious that `userId` is annotated with `@FXML`, but `passwordfield` is not. This would allow the `FXMLLoader` to inject `userId`, but not `passwordfield`, since the visibility is package private, not `public`... Do you get a `NullPointerException`?

Comment: AHHA! you have just solved several of my problems! I am completely new to FXML/FavaFX and didnt know i need to have an @FXML tag before every line that i want to initialise?  Add it as an answer and i will accept.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any member of the controller class not annotated with `@FXML` is not accessible to the `FXMLLoader`, unless it's visibility is `public`.

This results in the `FXMLLoader` not being able to inject the `passwordfield` to the controller which results in a `NullPointerException` when dereferencing it.

Every member the `FXMLLoader` should be able to access needs to be annotated with `@FXML` seperately.

The following declaration should work:

```
@FXML
TextField userId;
@FXML
TextField passwordfield;
```

and so would

```
@FXML
TextField userId,
          passwordfield;
```

since in this case the targets of the annotation are both fields.

Comment: I had this same issue.  Was trying to use `.getText()` and getting `NullPointerException` and couldn't figure out why.  After seeing many possible reasons across the interweb I stumbled on this and saw straight away I had forgotten to `@FXML` annotate one of my fields.